# Python: pandas to discard all rows if any of the row item is null

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
ID  IndentNo    PO_Ref_No
 1  10023       470089AB
 2  10023       470089DC
 3  10023   
 4  10024       674005TT
 5  10024       674005LP
 6  10024       674005TN
```

**Objective:** I want to drop the entire row against `IndentNo`= 10024 because it has got the `PO_Ref_No` for all 3 rows.

So the Resultant `df` would be like :

```
ID  IndentNo    PO_Ref_No
 1  10023       470089AB
 2  10023       470089DC
 3  10023
```

Is there any clue on how to do the same efficiently? If I use below:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['PO_Ref_No']),1,0)
df = df.loc[df['Flag']!=1]
```

But this would take away `ID` number 3 of `IndentNo` 10023.

Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: df[df['IndentNo'].isin(df[df['PO_Ref_No'].isna()]['IndentNo'].unique())] should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is for how to discard all rows if any of the row item is **not** null:

You can check missing values and test if per groups at least one has `NaN` by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df = df[df['PO_Ref_No'].isna().groupby(df['IndentNo']).transform('any')]
print (df)
   ID  IndentNo PO_Ref_No
0   1     10023  470089AB
1   2     10023  470089DC
2   3     10023       NaN
```

Or get all groups with `NaN`s by filtering by `isna` and then filter original column `IndentNo` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for membership:

```
df = df[df['IndentNo'].isin(df.loc[df['PO_Ref_No'].isna(), 'IndentNo'])]
print (df)
   ID  IndentNo PO_Ref_No
0   1     10023  470089AB
1   2     10023  470089DC
2   3     10023       NaN
```

Slow, but possible is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('IndentNo').filter(lambda x: x['PO_Ref_No'].isna().any())
```